# Variable Sized Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

I guess my question is whether the following is valid C

```
int main(void) {
  int r = 3;
  int k[r];
  return 0;
}
```

If so, would some one care to explain why it does not work in Microsoft's C compiler, but in GCC, and when it was added to the C standard.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a GCC extension that the current MSVC does not support. You can replace it in MSVC fairly easily with an _alloca (a stack allocation that requires no manual deallocation on the part of the programmer):

```
#include <malloc.h>

...

int *k = (int *)_alloca(sizeof(*k)*r);
```

Comment: It was a GCC extension, but was codified into C99. MSVC indeed does not support it yet.  Note also that on Linux, it's alloca(), not _alloca, and is in <alloca.h>

Comment: I have always used this, but did not get the error until I used windows

this clears up my confusion

Answer (score 13):

It is in C99. MSVC only supports C89.

Answer (score 9):

The [C99 standard](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=215) added variable-length arrays, but other vendors such as GCC added them much earlier.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry this is not an answer, but I'd like to point out a potential problem with using variable-length arrays.  Most of the code that I have come across looks like this.

```
void foo(int n)
{
    int bar[n];
    .
    .
}
```

There is no explicit error checking here.  A large `n` can easily cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

It is a GCC extension that the current MSVC does not support. You can replace it in MSVC fairly easily with an _alloca (a stack allocation that requires no manual deallocation on the part of the programmer)

yes but it is limited to 1mb