# how am i able to declare an array with variable length determined at runtime in C++?

Tags: c++, new-operator

Please check this code out it compiles and runs absolutely fine..
The question is that when i started learning c++ (turbo c++) i never was able to declare an array of any type as ..

```
datatype var[variable_set_at_runtime];
```

and i took it for granted that this cant be possible in latest gcc compilers...but surprisingly this is possible...

So my related question is that whats the need of new operator then??

I know that new operator does a lot of things including dynamically allocating memory at runtime in heap,returning an address to that resource...etc..

What difference i feel is that my code dynamically allocates the memory on stack while new does it on heap?? is this the only difference...

i am really astonished after writing something like this as i could not do this when i started learning c++ and ...to add to it i can do this for custom data types too... :-O

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
int main()
{
    int a;
    cin>>a;
    int ch[a];
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
        ch[i]=i+1;
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
        cout<<"\n\nch=="<<ch[i];
    A obj[a];
    cin>>obj[a-1].a;
    cin>>obj[a-1].b;
    cout<<"\n\n obj.a,obj.b=="<<obj[a-1].a<<" , "<<obj[a-1].b;
}
```

Please shed some light..

Thanks.

Comment: 7 responses within 5 minutes... awesome.. :-0

Comment: Interesting: MSVC still does not support this. So your code would not compile into MS world :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> and i took it for granted that this
>   cant be possible in latest gcc
>   compilers...but surprisingly this is
>   possible...

It is legal in C, but not C++. GCC might allow it depending on compiler flags, but if you compile your code as strict C++ (which you should), dynamic-length arrays are not allowed, and you have to use `new`. (I'm surprised no one has mentioned this little detail yet)

Apart from this, the two other big differences are that:

- data on the stack is automatically cleaned up when it goes out of scope
- only something like 1MB is typically allocated for the stack. Large datastructures should go on the heap instead.

But really, the single most important point is the first one -- it's not valid C++. (And as Neil pointed out, it is not valid in C++0x either. There are no plans of adding this to C++)

Comment: And before anyone asks, it appears not be valid C++0x either.

Comment: Furthermore, it's legal only in C99.

Comment: btw how is C++0x pronounced??

Comment: @ashishsony, it seems that it will be C++10 rather than C++0x, because noone know how to pronounce C++0x correctly :)

Comment: See plus plus oh ecks?
Of course, 0x is just a nickname, because no one is yet sure which year it'll be out. I think the hope for a C++09 are dwindling, so hopefully we'll get a C++10 instead.

Comment: Or C++0xa ... maybe C++0xb :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have to allocate it on the heap, using **new** :

```
int* ch = new int[ a ];
```

but don't forget to deallocate it after usage :

```
delete [] ch;
```

A better way would be to use a [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) that does exactly what you want.

Comment: I am new to C++, I have tried your suggestion. I just want to know whether my code is right or not. I put this `delete [] ch;` at the bottom in the `main()` function, right? I mean, in the end of the entire code. I just want to learn it as a newbie, I will use `std::vector` in the future.)

Answer (score 1):

You'd use new:

```
datatype *var=new [variable_set_at_runtime];
```

and then delete it when you're finished with it:

```
delete[] var;
```

Answer (score 1):

now, There is 2 different approaches, either you use the new operator as other answers have been suggesting, but that have some problems for example you have to make sure to not leak any memory.

I would rather suggest to use STL to handle this kind of stuff, a list for example.

That way you don't have to handle the memory management yourself, and the code looks neater.

look here for some guide: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/

Comment: +1: STL is the most appropriate solution for implementing dynamic arrays in C++. Something like std::vector<> is a nice replacement for arrays.

Comment: @D.Shawley Do you think which is better for this kind of function (implement dynamic arrays in C++) between apvector and vector? I find apvector quite by accident, and I find it is pretty easy and convenient.

Answer (score 0):

The stack is a very small amount of memory. You should only allocate small, temporary things on the stack. Large or non-temporary objects would do well to be allocated on the heap.

Yes, that will require careful memory management.

Answer (score 0):

Things allocated "automatically" will disappear when the allocation goes out of scope. Things allocated "on the heap" with `new` will not.

Answer (score 0):

Any variable declared as you have specified is put on the stack.  Once it goes out of scope, it will no longer be valid.  However, if you use new to declare your array, it will be allocated on the heap and remain valid until you call delete on it.

Answer (score 0):

You still need the `new` operator to allocate things on the heap and this is required if you want them to survive beyond the scope of the function they're created in.

The stack is often also far more limited than the heap in terms of size and I'd love to see a linked list (or *any* non-array collection) of objects created using the variable length array declaration method :-)

No, I think `new` may be around for a little while longer.

Answer (score 0):

"What difference i feel is that my code dynamically allocates the memory on stack while new does it on heap?? is this the only difference..."

Thats exactly the difference.  Just remember.  The stack has limited space whereas the heap has none of the restrictions (Well obviously it has some restrictions ... try making a 4 Gig allocation for one ;)).  In general id say that if you know your stack allocation will be relatively small then use your method, otherwise create it on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Use _alloca. See my answer here for [Variable Sized Arrays in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054085/variable-sized-arrays-in-c/1054154#1054154)

Comment: Don't use `malloc`/`free` series allocation in c++ unless you need them to interact with a c library, because they don't call constructors and destructors the way `new`/`delete` do.

Comment: OP has an `int` array and a POD struct array with no constructor. If he were to instead use a 1st class `class`, but still wanted stack allocation (for example, if the code were performance-sensitive), then he can call in-place `new` and manually call the destructor.