# What g++ flags will make a runtime-sized array on stack cause compiler error?

Tags: c++, arrays, g++

Creating a array on the stack with the size determined at runtime is allowed by default with g++:

```
int size;
cout << "Enter array size: " 
cin >> size;
MyObject stack_array[size];
```

According answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079288/how-am-i-able-to-declare-an-array-with-variable-length-determined-at-runtime-in), it's a bad idea and I agree.
Apparently I should be able to use a g++ flag to enforce strict/standard C++ and get a compiler error.  The code still compiles even with the following flags:

```
g++ -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c++0x
```

How can I prevent this code from compiling?

Here is my version info:

```
g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.5 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --with-multiarch-defaults=i386-linux-gnu --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.5 --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-gold --enable-ld=default --with-plugin-ld=ld.gold --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4)
```

Comment: `-ansi` conflicts with `-std=c++0x`. In C++ mode `-ansi` means the same as `-std=c++98`. Not an answer because the error should be generated in either mode.

Comment: Does the compiler generate a warning? If so `-pedantic-errors` should help, although I concede `-Werror` should do this any way.

Comment: +1: Good question, but don't write answers in questions please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my computer (Arch Linux, GCC 4.6.2) using `g++ -pedantic file.cpp` returns

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:7:12: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘arry’ [-Wvla]
```

Comment: -pedantic gives the warning; the addition of -Werror keeps it from compiling.  It turns out my original options would have worked if my makefile was actually compiling the source files using those options (oops).  As it turned out, those options were only used to link.  :o  Once I fixed the makefile it worked fine.

Answer (score 8):

Upgrade your compiler (it needs to support `-Wvla` flag, you can hunt for it in the changelogs or just upgrade to 4.6.2). 4.6 will correctly reject it:

```
> g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -Werror -pedantic -o vla.exe vla.cpp
vla.cpp: In function 'int main()':
vla.cpp:3:19: error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'array' [-Werror=vla]
vla.cpp:3:9: error: unused variable 'array' [-Werror=unused-variable]
cc1plus.exe: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Also, `-ansi` is the same as `-std=c++98`, so don't use that flag if you want C++11.

Comment: Well, upgrading to 4.6 is a good idea anyway, especially if you want C++11.

Comment: That may be true, but unless there was a specific regression in 4.5.2 it doesn't really explain the lack of error in the OP's case.

Comment: @CharlesBailey you are correct.  I found that my makefile was not compiling the individual source files with the flags, only the final build of the executable.  Boneheaded oversight on my part.  -pedantic -Werror is all that is needed.

Comment: @Pete: See, use a sane build system next time. :P